# Entity Framework Code First The model backing the '<Database>' context has changed since the database was created

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there a way of determining the differences between the database context you are using and the database you are connecting to so that you can update your database accordingly when you receive the message:

The model backing the '' context has changed since the database was created.

?

Answer (score 1):

No but you can change connection string, create database again and use some diff tool to compare databases (for example Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate, or tools from RedGate).

Comment: Hmmm, its rather annoying as I have just done what you have suggested, but generated all the scripts from the databases in question and they match, however the hash that the EdmMetadata holds is different...  thanks for the idea though, at least I know that the databases are the same and I am not going around the bend